# Can .csproj Switch native code by platform?

Tags: c#, .net-core, .net-standard

I'm learning C#. (sorry I'm not native English speeker.)
I'm creating multi platform library in dotnet core.
I want to switch platform in one method.
I tryed `RuntimeInformation.IsOSPlatform()` then successed I want to do.

I heard that I can change the code to be executed for each OS by the property of `project.csproj`.
but I couldn't do that.

I want to do this.

project.csproj

```xml
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>library</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>netstandard2.0</TargetFramework>
    <PackageId>MemoryInfo</PackageId>
    <Version>1.0.0</Version>
    <Authors>foobar</Authors>
    <Company>foobar</Company>
    <EnableDefaultCompileItems>false</EnableDefaultCompileItems>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Compile Include="Program.cs" />
  </ItemGroup>

//(add comment) Switch Native Code
  <ItemGroup Condition="'$(TargetsWindows)' == 'true'">
    <Compile Include="Linux/native.cs" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup Condition="'$(TargetsLinux)' == 'true'">
    <Compile Include="Windows/native.cs" />
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

Program.cs

```
~~
  public long GetMemorySize() //library method
  {
    NativeMemoryinfo mem = new NativeMemoryinfo();
    return mem.GetMemorySize(); //access to each platform code
  }
~~
```

Linux/native.cs

```
~~
  class NativeMemoryinfo
  {
    public long GetMemorySize()
    {
        Code for Linux(/proc/meminfo...)
     }
  }
~~
```

Windows/native.cs

```
~~
  class NativeMemoryinfo
  {
    public long GetMemorySize()
    {
        Code for Windows(Kernel32....)
     }
  }
~~
```

Maybe, I think I'm misunderstood or in the wrong way.
Can I do this way?
my research, I found something called "interop" [this](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/master/Documentation/coding-guidelines/interop-guidelines.md), but what is the relationship with this?

Thank you.

Comment: are you making a nuget?

Comment: "I heard that project.csproj can switch native code." You might also hear that computers can write programs themselves. Please stick to the official documentation, not somebody's imagination.

Comment: sorry my English is so bad. I changed sentence.
I realized that I was making a mistake. 
I thought [this](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/master/Documentation/coding-guidelines/interop-guidelines.md) "interop" could be the content of my question.

Answer (score 2):

The feature you are trying to use with csproj is normally used to target the different frameworks in .NET, not to target different OS. See this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/frameworks

What you are trying to do can be achieved by interfaces. Have an interface `INativeMemoryinfo` and initialize it to the windows or linux version based on `if (RuntimeInformation.IsOSPlatform()  == "")`.

Side note: since you are working o a library, I suggest using .net standard instead of .net core.

Answer (score -2):

if (RuntimeInformation.IsOSPlatform() == "").

Comment: that's in the question